# How to change Windows PE registry values from within Windows PE

Tags: windows-registry, windows-pe

I have a Windows PE (Win7) image which I can boot but the hostname is randomly set. I know I can change that behavior by setting the following registry keys:

```
SOFTWARE\ControlSet001\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName\ComputerName  = computername
```

and

```
SYSTEM\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinPE\SetComputerName  = 0
```

It works if I mount the WIM image on a second computer, mount the hives, edit the keys and unmount everything again and then apply the WIM file.

But what I need is to make these changes within a running Windows PE instance. I already tried to mount the hives there, but it only works for the SYSTEM hive and not the SOFTWARE hive.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [PE Network Configurator](http://pierre-mounir.freehostia.com/) :

> PE Network Configurator or PENetCfg is a stand-alone utility that
>   allows you to start and configure networking in Microsoft WinPE and
>   BartPE.
>
> With PENetCfg you can do the following:
>
> - Enable and start networking support if it's not started yet.
> - List all Ethernet adapters on the running machine and set TCP/IP properties (IP Addresses, Default Gateways, DNS Servers, WINS Servers
>
>   - any number of them) and switch between using static and dynamic (DHCP) TCP/IP settings at any time.
> - Select Link Speed/Duplex Mode of a broad range of Ethernet adapters.
> - Add any Domain, workgroup, or Server to browse its resources and map and disconnect network drives.
> - Change computer name and join workgroup.
> - Release and renew the IP address of any Ethernet adapter.
> - Change the MAC address of any Ethernet adapter on the fly.
> - Use network profiles to automate configuring network settings. For more information about using the network profiles, see the included
>     readme.txt in the downloaded package.

The computer name can be preset in the file `PNETCFG.INI` under `[NetID]`.
For example :

```
[NetID]
ComputerName=the-name
Workgroup=workgroup
```

I have never used this application and cannot guarantee that it still works
with the latest Windows builds.